# Ubuntu Error Windows Opens every few Minutes

Tags: upgrade, 13.04

I have been having a problem with my installation of Ubuntu 13.04 ever since I upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04. Around every 5 min or so an error window will come up that says that Ubuntu has encountered an error. This has also been going on my Media center that is running Ubuntu 13.04. It was also from an original Ubuntu 12.04 installation that I upgraded.

Comment: Try sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade.
I feels its much better to make a clean install instead of upgrading.

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: Peter, I am not a noob to Ubuntu or Linux. I have updated my repository and then upgraded but even still I get problems.

Comment: Mitch, I will have to wait until I get the message again here in a few mins to post exactly what it says.

Comment: Mitch, I just added a link to a screen shot on the original post.

Comment: If you hit "Report Problem," and then, I believe, "Show Details," you may be able to provide us with the error, verbatim.  The error dialog has no pertinent information in it, unfortunately.

Comment: Well, it will not be long until the message appears again. Once it does I will gather the extra information.

Comment: I had this too, even deleted that folder with the errors etc, but after a while, it will not pop anymore.

Comment: Ok, I just added some more info above.

Comment: Executable path, problem type, and crash counter (in particular) would probably help you isolate the issue further.  The latter would probably be a 'dead giveaway' as to whether this has been the exact same issue every time.

Try to look at each of those individual subtopics of the error report, and let us know what stands out.  The aforementioned three would be helpful to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have been playing around and found that if I run this command:

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/apport
```

I can change the "1" to a "0" and it will disable the anoying popup window telling me that there is an error.

Then after that run:

```
sudo restart apport
```